# Make sure internal link URL parameters for statistical tracking are not seen as different pages

Tags: url, hyperlink, get, search-engine

I want to add some parameters to my URLs so that I can identify if a page was opened by a visitor clicking on a homepage link, the top navigation, the bottom navigation, etc. So something like:

- http://url.com/article/123?ref=topnav
- http://url.com/article/123?ref=bottomnav
- ..://url.com/article/123?ref=homepage

(can't post more than two links here)

However, I want to make sure that the search engine does not thing this is a separate page and that I have a lot of duplicate content on my page. I figured there is some "Industry Standard" way of doing this, to make it clear that my parameters are just internal flags for statistics, and not indicative of different content. But I can't find relevant search results when Googling; not sure how to search for this.

So my question: is there a way I should name or use URL parameters to ensure search engines are aware of the significance of these links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a set of parameters available. They are:

```
Campaign Source (utm_source)
Required. Use utm_source to identify a search engine, newsletter name, or other source. 
Example: utm_source=google

Campaign Medium (utm_medium)
Required. Use utm_medium to identify a medium such as email or cost-per- click. 
Example: utm_medium=cpc

Campaign Term (utm_term)
Used for paid search. Use utm_term to note the keywords for this ad. 
Example: utm_term=running+shoes

Campaign Content (utm_content)    
Used for A/B testing and content-targeted ads. Use utm_content to differentiate ads or links that point to the same URL. 
Examples: utm_content=logolink or utm_content=textlink

Campaign Name (utm_campaign)
Used for keyword analysis. Use utm_campaign to identify a specific product promotion or strategic campaign. 
Example: utm_campaign=spring_sale
```

More can be read here: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867

Not sure if this is 'industry standard', but at least it's Analytics-supported.

Comment: You definitively should not use those for internal links. When Google Analytics sees someone arrive with campaign parameters, it will end the current session and start a new session with the new information, effectively breaking external campaigns attribution.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Google, when indexing pages, ignores everything after the `#` in your URLs, so use # instead of `?` ... Then, for your SEO purposes, Google will consider:

`http://example.com/pagename.html`
and
`http://example.com/pagename.html#var1=FOO&var2=BAR` to be the same page.

**2)** You can also set in the head of your pages:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/pagename.html" />`

see: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

**3)** As far as reporting goes, in google analytics, they support use of `#` as query string delimiter, see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor

**4)** In your google analytics profile, you can also set it to exclude query string parameters. See: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1010249

**I prefer method #1**. All of my tracking URLs for campagins and all internal links and logic use `#` as the query string delimeter so I can maximize my link juice to the canonical domain (no www subdomain in my canonical) I set in .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```